# Какова сложность (Big O Notation) операции grep текстового файла, если мы проверяем строку по частичному совпадению?

Tags: list, grep, итераторы

Если я правильно понимаю, то сложность операции команды grep с текстовым файлом будет O(n), если мы ищем строку по полному совпадению.

Если мы грепаем файл по частичному совпадению строк, сложность операции увеличится до следующего уровня?

Comment: Если без регулярок, то думаю всё-равно будет `O(n)`, а если с регуляркой, то сложно сказать, зависит от регулярки )

Comment: @CrazyElf понял, спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GNU Grep](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html)

> The grep command operates partly via a set of automata that are
> designed for efficiency, and partly via a slower matcher that takes
> over when the fast matchers run into unusual features like
> back-references. When feasible, the **Boyer–Moore** fast string searching
> algorithm is used to match a single fixed pattern, and the
> **Aho–Corasick** algorithm is used to match multiple fixed patterns.

таблицу сравнение алгоритмов поиска подстроки в строке, в том числе и вышеупомянутых можно посмотреть в этой статье - [Поиск подстроки в строке](https://neerc.ifmo.ru/wiki/index.php?title=%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%B2_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B5)

Comment: спасибо большое!